# How to compare two variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to match two variables.

```
var this_roll;
```

and

```
var last_roll;
```

I have this code, that i want the output of "win" or "losse". The output should be "win" if `last_roll` and `this_roll` have the same value and "lose" if not

```js
"use strict";
var x;
var win_losse = 'losse';
var last_roll;
var last_bet;
var this_roll = $('#past')[0].childNodes[9].textContent;
var bet_input = document.getElementById('betAmount').value=x;
var roll_time = $('#banner')[0].childNodes[0].textContent;
var base_bet = 5;

function thisRoll() {

 console.log(this_roll);
 if (this_roll == 0) {
  this_roll = 'green';
 } else if ((this_roll >= 1) && (this_roll <= 7)) {
  this_roll = 'red';
 } else if ((this_roll >= 8) && (this_roll <= 14)) {
  this_roll = 'black';
 }
}

function compare() {

 if (this_roll == last_roll) {
  win_losse = 'win';
 } else {
  win_losse = 'losse';
 }
 console.log(win_lose);
}

function lastRoll() {

 console.log(this_roll);
 if (this_roll == 0) {
  last_roll = 'green';
 } else if ((this_roll >= 1) && (this_roll <= 7)) {
  last_roll = 'red';
 } else if ((this_roll >= 8) && (this_roll <= 14)) {
  last_roll = 'black';
 }
}

function bet() {

 if (win_losse == 'win') {
  x = base_bet;
 } else if (win_losse == 'losse') {
  x = last_bet * 2;
 }
}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: *"it didn't seem to work"* doesn't tell us anything. What result did you get, and what result did you expect? Separately, please pull the various disconnected parts above into a single [mcve], ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: *"and this sets the value of this_roll"* Nothing in the code block following that sets the value of `this_roll`.

Comment: Thanks just saw that, i have changed it

Comment: I have edited the post and put it into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for sure

```js
"use strict";
//Removed the global x variable
//Removed the global win_lose variable
var last_roll = $('#past')[0].childNodes[8].textContent;
var last_bet;
var this_roll = $('#past')[0].childNodes[9].textContent;
var bet_input = document.getElementById('betAmount').value=x;
//Removede the Roll_time variable because it wasn't used
var base_bet = 5;

function ThisRoll(this_roll) {
 var rollhisThis; //Added a local  variable
 if (this_roll === 0) {
  rollhisThis = 'green';
 } else if ((this_roll >= 1) && (this_roll <= 7)) {
  rollhisThis = 'red';
 } else if ((this_roll >= 8) && (this_roll <= 14)) {
  rollhisThis = 'black';
 }
 return rollhisThis; //Added return
}
var thisRoll = ThisRoll(this_roll); //Added a new global variable
console.log(thisRoll);

function LastRoll(last_roll) {

 var rollhisLast; //Added a local variable
 if (last_roll === 0) {
  rollhisLast = 'green';
 } else if ((last_roll >= 1) && (last_roll <= 7)) {
  rollhisLast = 'red';
 } else if ((last_roll >= 8) && (last_roll <= 14)) {
  rollhisLast = 'black';
 }
 return rollhisLast; //Added return
}
var lastRoll = LastRoll(last_roll); //Added a new global variable
console.log(LastRoll);

function compare(thisRoll, lastRoll) {
    var win_lose; //Added a local win_lose variable
    if (thisRoll !== lastRoll) {
        win_lose = 'lose';
    } else {
        win_lose = 'win';
    }
    return win_lose; //Added return
}
var winLose = compare(thisRoll, lastRoll); //Added a gloabl variable
console.log(winLose);

function bet() {

 if (win_losse == 'win') {
  x = base_bet;
 } else if (win_losse == 'losse') {
  x = last_bet * 2;
 }
}
console.log(x);
```