# How to compare if two variables reference the same object in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, reference

I am new to JavaScript and getting my hands on the spread operator.
I understand that it will deep copy the top-level elements of an array or object but shallow copy the nested arrays or objects.
I wanted to see it action and hence the code below but was unable to get the required output as per my understanding.

```js
const originalObject = {
  name: 'Alice',
  address: {
    street: '123 Main St',
    city: 'Anytown',
  },
};

const copiedObject = { ...originalObject };

console.log(copiedObject.name === originalObject.name); // Expected Output: false but Outputs: true

originalObject.address.city = 'Newtown';

console.log(copiedObject.address.city); // Output: "Newtown" (modification affects both objects)
console.log(originalObject.address.city);

console.log(copiedObject.address === originalObject.address); // Output: true (Can we understand this means both has a reference to the same object?)
```

Shouldn't it give an output as false?
console.log(copiedObject.name === originalObject.name);

Could someone explain in simpler terms how can I visualise it in code and also compare if two properties share the same reference in javascript?

Similar questions on stackoverflow thay I went through but couldn't find an answer:

1. [How to check if two vars have the same reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685079/how-to-check-if-two-vars-have-the-same-reference)
2. [How to compare two variables in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561635/how-to-compare-two-variables-in-javascript)
3. [Compare if two variables reference the same object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41967443/compare-if-two-variables-reference-the-same-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Spread syntax does not deep-copy anything; it's *strictly* a shallow copy. The property values of the source object are copied (as values) to the destination object.

Comment: What do you mean by "*it will deep copy the top-level elements*"?

Comment: Did you mean to `console.log(copiedObject === originalObject);`?

Comment: For strings, there is no difference between "deep" and "shallow" copy. Since they are immutable, there is not even a difference between "copy" and "share" for them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare if two variables reference the same object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41967443/compare-if-two-variables-reference-the-same-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Voting to close since the flagged duplicate covers everything that the answers here do. Simply because the OP linked to the duplicate in the question does not stop it being a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitives are always compared by value, objects (including arrays and functions) are always compared by reference.

Thats about as simple as it can get.

[Primitives in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) are strings, numbers, bigints, booleans, symbols, undefined, and null.

Everything else is an object

You’ve got two questions in here, though.

The first is “how does JS compare variables” - answered above.

The second is “how does the spread operator work (on objects or arrays)”

That was answered by Pointy in the comments, the spread operator always creates a shallow copy of the thing (object or array) you’re using it on.

That means that any object defined within the object you’re spreading is NOT shallow/deep cloned at all, its reference will be the same in object you’ve created with the spread operator.

So if you modify a property in that nested object in an object cloned using the spread operator, it’s also modified in the original object, because it’s the same reference, it’s the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small function that checks if two things are types that are references, and if so checks if they are equal.

```js
const isSameReference = (a, b) => {
  return a === b && a != null && ["object", "function"].includes(typeof a)
}

const originalObject = {
  name: 'Alice',
  address: {
    street: '123 Main St',
    city: 'Anytown',
  },
};

const copiedObject = { ...originalObject };

console.log(isSameReference(copiedObject.name, originalObject.name));

console.log(isSameReference(copiedObject.address, originalObject.address));
```

Comment: Checking `typeof b === t` is unnecessary when you already check `a === b`